# Cesar encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to write a function that, given an original message and an offset, computes and returns the encrypted message:

```
def cesar_encryption (message, offset = 1):
 encrypted_message = ""

 for i in range(len(message)):
   char = message[i]
   if (char.islower()):
      encrypted_message += chr((ord(char) + offset)
 return encrypted_message

print (cesar_encryption("I LOVE NATURE", 1))
```

I have a problem in my code. Please. How could I solve it?

Comment: What is the problem ? Wrong result ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: `if char.islower()` : no what is lowercase in the input string, condition is never true so

Comment: Your function will return an empty string because of your `if (char.islower())` as you pass a string in full cap, so you code will pass in the if, try passing `"i love nature"` instead

Comment: This will help you - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cesar_encryption (message, offset = 1):
    encrypted_message = ""

    for char in message:
        encrypted_message += chr(ord(char) + offset)
    return encrypted_message

print (cesar_encryption("I LOVE NATURE", 1)) # J!MPWF!OBUVSF
```

Just remove `.islower()`, because you don't need it.

More about this can be learned at - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/

Comment: Index iteration isn't neede, you can directly use `for char in message:`